# I cannot deployed domain on standalone server

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

Good day! I'm new in Mule...and English language:). I have Anypoint Studio with Server 3.8.4 CE and mule-standalone-3.8.1 in this computer, and mule-standalone-3.8.1 on another. I create a project in studio and check. It's work !. After them I choose Export -> AnypointStudio Project. And I make .zip file with this project, copy file on directory %MULE_HOME%/domain for two standalone server 3.8.1 on this PC and another. On this computer - domain deployed, on another - failed. Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:wmq="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq/current/mule-wmq-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd">
    <wmq:connector name="WMQ" hostName="10.0.12.38" port="1414" queueManager="MQ_ADM" username="*******" transportType="CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP" validateConnections="true" doc:name="WMQ" />
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean class="JMSAQ.JMSAQTest" name="JMSAQTest" id="JMSAQTest">
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>
    <flow name="wmq-to-aqFlow">
        <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="MQ_QUEUE" connector-ref="WMQ" doc:name="WMQ" />
        <logger message="#[message.inboundProperties['Jms_Sender']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <logger message="Read!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <set-variable variableName="jms_sender" value="#[message.inboundProperties['Jms_Sender']]" doc:name="Variable" />
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[flowVars['jms_sender'] == 'MQ1']">
                <invoke name="Invoke" object-ref="JMSAQTest" method="enqueueMessage" methodArguments="#[payload]" />
            </when>
            <when expression="#[flowVars['jms_sender'] == 'MQ2']">
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="src/main/wmq" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <logger message="finish" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Error in second server on another computer:

```
2017-08-03 12:48:07,964 [WrapperListener_start_runner] ERROR org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication - null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'wmq:connector'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":property-placeholder, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":global-property, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":configuration, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":notifications, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-agent, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-flow-construct, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":sub-flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-model, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-interceptor-stack, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-filter, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transformer, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":processor-chain, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-empty-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":invoke, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":set-payload, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-intercepting-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-queue-store, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-processing-strategy}' is expected.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
...................
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wmq:connector is available to enterprise edition of Mule. Propably on other server you have Community Runtime and on local you're running Enterprise Runtime.

If not, you're propably missing jars - more info here
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mule-wmq-transport-reference

Comment: But zip file with project have all jars. I make project on AnypointStudio, add all jars, deployed, convinced that everything works and export. Close AnypointStudio. Download mule-standalone-3.8.1 and unzip in my computer and in server. Copy zip file with ptoject in directory  %MULE_HOME%/domain in my PC and server. If I run Mul on my pc -
 domain deployed, on server - domain failed. But you are right, and wmq:connector have type Select, not Community

Comment: Try copying these jars into %MULE_HOME%/lib/user/ . I'm not convinced it would help but it's worth trying.

Comment: If I copy them there, mule does not start

Comment: What's the exception?